# Attempt to invoke virtual method-FAILURE : App Crashed

Tags: java, android, retrofit

While trying to run the app , it crashes and says `"Attempt to invoke virtual method"`. Below is the error found in the logcat.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.sayantan.moviebugs, PID: 1694
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.List com.example.sayantan.moviebugs.model.MoviesResponse.getResults()' on a null object reference
            at com.example.sayantan.moviebugs.MainActivity$2.onResponse(MainActivity.java:132)
            at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:68)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5885)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687)
```

Below is the Json code snippet from `main_activity.java` file:

```
eCall<MoviesResponse> call = apiService.getPopularMovies(BuildConfig.THE_MOVIE_DB_API_TOKEN);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<MoviesResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<MoviesResponse> call, Response<MoviesResponse> response) {
                List<Movie> movies = response.body().getResults();

                //Collections.sort(movies, Movie.BY_NAME_ALPHABETICAL);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(new MoviesAdapter(getApplicationContext(), movies));
                recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
                if (swipeContainer.isRefreshing()){
                    swipeContainer.setRefreshing(false);
                }
```

Below is the snippet from the model file :

```
  public void setPage(int page) {
    this.page = page;
}

public List<Movie> getResults()
{
    return results;
}

public List<Movie> getMovies() {
    return results;
}

public void setResults(List<Movie> results) {
    this.results = results;
}
```

Comment: `response.body()` is null. Check that you're getting a valid response from the server.

Comment: No , I am not getting a valid response from the server How to fix that Michael?

Comment: That depends entirely on the behaviour of the server you're obtaining the data from. Is your initial request correct? Was the remote API also created by you, and if so, could it be a bug in the API?

Comment: I wonder what is the meaning of `virtual method` in java context

Answer (score 2):

A Retrofit onResponse is called when there is a response, this means it will be also called when there is an error. The body (getBody()) in this case is null, this will lead to an java.lang.NullPointerException if you try to use it.

An example how to use Retrofit in your case:

```
if (response.isSuccessful())
{
    List<Movie> movies = response.body().getResults();

    ... // Other code
}
else
{
    Log.d("SOME_TAG", "Error code: " + response.code());
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That worked. But I think I have a problem with the connection.
Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Can't really help you with a connection problem. I normally use Postman to debug problems with server calls: https://www.getpostman.com